# Using the same double in different functions

Tags: c++

I have two functions which use the same doubles ie like

in the .h I declare

```
class MyClass :  {
public :

    double arg1, arg2;

    void getVarA(double a, double b);
    void getVarB(double a, double b);
    void Reset();
}
```

and in my .C I have something like

```
void MyClass::Reset(){
    arg1 = 0.0f;
    arg2 = 0.0f;
}

void MyClass::getVarA(double a, double b){

    arg1+=2*a;
    arg2+=2*b;

    return arg1-arg2;
}


void MyClass::getVarB(double a, double b){

    arg1+=2+a;
    arg2+=2+b;

    return arg1-arg2;
}
```

The problem is that in principle I want to create a copy of arg1,arg2 each one taking values in each function (ie in each function to be possible to take different values) so that arg1,arg2 dont "speak" between the two different functions and whenever I change the arg1 in getVarA function not to commute with the arg1 in getVarB function.

Sorry, probably my example is poorly phrased but I am just newbie..

thanks

Comment: `arg1` and `arg2` don't have an initialization. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Just edited my initial post - thanks

Comment: I think you might need `arg3` and `arg4` (on top of some initialization).

Comment: When your argX variables are members then the functions have different side effects. It's unclear why do you change the values and don't use them.

Comment: It looks like you want each function to "remember" something about the previous times it was called, so that the return value depends on what function calls have been made in the past.  And you want each function to have its own memory, unaffected by any calls to the other function.  Is that an accurate summary of your question?

Comment: Just think about a change of design

Comment: @Darryl - yes, correct ! I would like each function to have independent behavior of the other(s) functions calls and the double (or whatever else) they use are not altered by another function call

Answer (score 0):

Make  your variables arg1, arg2 as function local variables.

```
void MyClass:getVarA(double a, double b) {
    double arg1, arg2;

    arg1+=2*a;
    arg2+=2*b

    return arg1-arg2
}


void MyClass:getVarB(double a, double b) {
    double arg1, arg2;

    arg1+=2+a;
    arg2+=2+b

    return arg1-arg2
}
```

They will become different variables. None of changes made in getVarA arg1, arg2 will affect arg1, arg2 from getVarB

**EDIT**
According to @harper comment, it is strongly recommended to avoid uninitialized variables. You can't assume initial value of `arg1` and `arg2` variables. Your should explicit set initial value

```
double arg1 = 0.0;
double arg2 = 0.0;
```

Comment: Do you propose this undefined behavior?

Comment: Author already had UB caused by uninitialized variables. I just answered author's question

Comment: yes, but the local variables wont work if one calls another function from inside the initial function, right ?

Comment: I don't clearly understand what behavior you want. Which variables should shared between two methods and which shouldn't?

Comment: Maybe static local variables will help you

Comment: arg1 and arg2 should be behave independent while calling the two functions. The problem is that if I call the first function and then the second, in the latter the arg1,arg2 already carry the values after the first function finished.

Comment: you can `reset` the values of `arg1` and `arg2` after your call the first function.

Answer (score 0):

"The problem is that in principle I want to create a copy of arg1,arg2"

You can do exactly that:

```
void MyClass::getVarA(double a, double b)
{
    double arg1Copy = arg1;
    double arg2Copy = arg2;
    arg1Copy+=2*a;
    arg2Copy+=2*b;

    return arg1Copy-arg2Copy;
}
```

Now arg1 and arg2 are not modified by your method. In fact you can even declare your method as `const` to inform the compiler that you do not want the data members to actually be modified by your method.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the following interpretation of your question:

- Each of the `getVar` functions is supposed to remember something about previous calls.  The value returned from a function call is supposed to change based on what calls were made to that function in the past.  For example, if you ran this code, `x1` and `x2` would have different values:

  ```
  MyClass mc;
  double x1 = mc.getVarA(1,1);
  double x2 = mc.getVarA(1,1);
  ```

  If you want `x1` and `x2` to have different values (because the first call is supposed to change what values are used in the second call), then this answer is appropriate.  If you want `x1` and `x2` to have the same value (because you don't want getVarA to remember anything about previous function calls), nnesterov's suggestion to use local variables is a better answer than this one.
- You want what is remembered about calls to getVarA to be independent from what is remembered about calls to getVarB.

With that in mind, here's the .h:

```
class MyClass {
public :

    double _varA1, _varA2;
    double _varB1, _varB2;

    MyClass();
    double getVarA(double a, double b);
    double getVarB(double a, double b);
    void Reset();
};
```

and here's the .c:

```
MyClass::MyClass(){
    Reset();
}

void MyClass::Reset(){
    _varA1 = 0.0;
    _varA2 = 0.0;
    _varB1 = 0.0;
    _varB2 = 0.0;
}

double MyClass::getVarA(double a, double b){

    _varA1 += 2*a;
    _varA2 += 2*b;

    return _varA1 - _varA2;
}

double MyClass::getVarB(double a, double b){

    _varB1 += 2+a;
    _varB2 += 2+b;

    return _varB1 - _varB2;
}
```

Things to notice:

- Each of the two `get` functions has its own set of instance variables.  That way you can change one function's data without changing the other function's data.
- The constructor calls `Reset()` so that the variables are initialized when you first create an instance of the class.  That way you can predict what will happen the first time you call each `get` function.
- The return type of the `get` functions has been changed to double, to match the implementation.